# Discord.js V14 ButtonBuilder() buttons stop updating/getting edited after the 15 minute SlashCommand timeout, how do I bypass the timeout?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, setinterval

```
// Update button labels every 30 seconds (or whatever you set it at)
setInterval(() => {
  const currentTimeET = DateTime.now().setZone("America/New_York");
  const formattedTimeET = currentTimeET.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE);

  const currentTimePT = DateTime.now().setZone("America/Los_Angeles");
  const formattedTimePT = currentTimePT.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE);

  const currentTimeCT = DateTime.now().setZone("America/Chicago");
  const formattedTimeCT = currentTimeCT.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE);

  const currentTimeBST = DateTime.now().setZone("Europe/London");
  const formattedTimeBST = currentTimeBST.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE);

  const currentTimeCEST = DateTime.now().setZone("Europe/Paris");
  const formattedTimeCEST = currentTimeCEST.toLocaleString(
    DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE
  );

  //build the new buttons with updating time after the original buttons are removed
  const newButtonZones = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId("buttonET")
      .setLabel(`EST/EDT - ${formattedTimeET}`)
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),

    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId("buttonPT")
      .setLabel(`PST/PDT - ${formattedTimePT}`)
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),

    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId("buttonCT")
      .setLabel(`CST/CDT - ${formattedTimeCT}`)
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),

    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId("buttonBST")
      .setLabel(`GMT/BST - ${formattedTimeBST}`)
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),

    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId("buttonCEST")
      .setLabel(`CET/CEST - ${formattedTimeCEST}`)
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
  );

  // Update the button labels
  buttonZones.components = newButtonZones.components;
  interaction.editReply({ components: [buttonZones] });
}, 30000);
```

[image: image of what the buttons look like (the timestamps inside the buttons update every 30 seconds)]

Like the title states, after the 15 minutes the timestamps inside the buttons no longer update. I imagine this is due to the fact that Discord doesn't allow replies to be edited after 15 minutes.

How do I bypass this and allow for the buttons to be updated permanently? I've seen a few posts pertaining to this subject, but none that deal with ButtonBuilder() updating.

(not sure if this matters but I use Luxon for the timestamps and PM2 to keep the node instance running after I've closed out of the hosting services terminal/console.)

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Do you get any console errors when you try to edit the message the 15th time? I’d assume discord would return an error if you were rate limited. You *could* just delete and re-send your message otherwise.

Comment: You cannot edit an interaction passed 15 minutes

Comment: Larry, the only problem I have with deleting and resending the message is the fact that it would push a notification to anyone subscribed to that channel every 15 minutes which would get quite annoying I imagine. Any other solution you can think of? Also yes, I get a Webhook expired token error aka the error thrown when you try to edit an interaction after 15 minutes.

Comment: Jaxon, I am aware of this which is why I'm hoping for a bypass as I've heard of other people doing similar bypasses.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some *heavy* research, I found this section in the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#editing-responses).

> "After the initial response, an interaction token is valid for 15 minutes, so this is the timeframe in which you can edit the response and send follow-up messages. You also cannot edit the ephemeral state of a message, so ensure that your first response sets this correctly."

So it looks like the **interaction token** times out after 15 mins, but not the actual message. Reply like so:

```js
// Sends the reply, and receives the message object from the sent 
interaction.reply("Some content/embeds/whatever")
.then((msg) => {
  // The replied message is now contained in the message variable.
  msg.edit("Some new content/embed/whatever")
  // All edit code should ideally go in here :)
  // Note the use of .edit(), not .editReply()
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.error(e)
})
```

If that happens to expire too, you can always store the message and channel ID from that `msg` variable and re-fetch the message after 15 mins:

```js
// Fetches channel object as "channel" variable
client.guilds.fetch(channelID).then((channel) => {
  // Fetches message object as "msg" variable
  channel.messages.fetch(messageID).then((msg) => {
    // Can now edit the message :)
    msg.edit("")
    // [...]
  })
})
```

Hopefully this helps! Stick a comment below if this still doesn't work.